# Gravar vários registros de uma tabela em outra com php

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho duas tabelas, uma escala com horários e outra relacionada chamada   agenda.

```
tabela escala
id_escala
hr_inicio

tabela agenda
id_agenda 
id_escala
hr_agendamento
```

Quero gravar no campo hr_agendamento na tabela agenda todos os horários da tabela escala que eu listar. Eu estou conseguindo gravar os id perfeitamente, porém os horários estão sendo gravados assim `00:00:00`.

O meu código:

```
<?php include("conectar.php");?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){       

        foreach($_POST['id_escala'] as $indice => $valor){
        $hr_agendamento   = $_POST['hr_agendamento'.$valor];


            $inserir = "INSERT INTO agenda
            (id_escala, hr_agendamento) VALUES ('".$valor."','".$hr_agendamento."')" 
            or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query($inserir) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }   
    // consulta do select de Serviços
    $selec = "SELECT * FROM escala limit  2";
    $exec = mysql_query($selec) or die(mysql_error());
    // Lista dados do checkbox 
?>

<form id="form1" action="" enctype=" multipart/form-data" method="post">
<?php
    while($dados = mysql_fetch_assoc($exec)){
        $valor_id_escala        =  $dados['id_escala'];

        $valor_hr_inicio     =  $dados['hr_inicio'];

?>
    <input style="margin-left:30px" name="id_escala[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $valor_id_escala ?>"/>




    <input type="hidden" name="hr_agendamento" value="<?php echo $valor_hr_inicio ?>" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $valor_hr_inicio ?></br>
<?php 
    } 
?>

    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="gravar" />
</form>
```

Comment: qual tipo de dados na coluna hr_inicio e hr_agendamento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Este input**

`<input type="hidden" name="hr_agendamento" value=......`

deverá ter o `name` dessa forma `name="hr_agendamento[]"`

> Esses colchetes tratam os elementos do mesmo nome como um array.

- Substitua esse trecho de código:

  ```
  if (isset($_POST['enviar'])){ 
    //array com os elementos dos inputs hr_agendamento
    $hr_agend = $_POST['hr_agendamento'];      

    foreach($_POST['id_escala'] as $indice => $valor){

      $hr_agendamento=$hr_agend[$indice];

      $inserir = "INSERT INTO agenda
      (id_escala, hr_agendamento) VALUES ('".$valor."','".$hr_agendamento."')" 
      or die(mysql_error());
      mysql_query($inserir) or die(mysql_error());
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: obrigado deu certo ta funcionando agora

Comment: desculpa sou novo aqui  ja estou lendo  obrigado.